# Synchronization within nested Parallel.For loops

Tags: c#, image-processing, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I wanted to turn a regular for loop into a Parallel.For loop.

This-

```
for (int i = 0; i < bitmapImage.Width; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmapImage.Height; x++)
    {
        System.Drawing.Color oc = bitmapImage.GetPixel(i, x);
        int gray = (int)((oc.R * 0.3) + (oc.G * 0.59) + (oc.B * 0.11));
        System.Drawing.Color nc = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(oc.A, gray, gray, gray);
        bitmapImage.SetPixel(i, x, nc);
    }
}
```

Into this-

```
Parallel.For(0, bitmapImage.Width - 1, i =>
{
    Parallel.For(0, bitmapImage.Height - 1, x =>
    {
        System.Drawing.Color oc = bitmapImage.GetPixel(i, x);
        int gray = (int)((oc.R * 0.3) + (oc.G * 0.59) + (oc.B * 0.11));
        System.Drawing.Color nc = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(oc.A, gray, gray, gray);
        bitmapImage.SetPixel(i, x, nc);
    });
});
```

It fails with message-

> Object is currently in use elsewhere.

at below line since multiple threads trying to access the non-thread safe reasources. Any idea how I can make this work?

```
System.Drawing.Color oc = bitmapImage.GetPixel(i, x);
```

Comment: You can't as you can't read or alter the resource simultaneously. Your first version is the only version that will work, adding locks will increase the overhead and make it slower than the first version.

Comment: @Igor Thanks. I thought the same.

Comment: As the Image is GUI-related class, it been made for single-thread access usage. You may try to make your computation on a stand-alone matrice, and after that update the image in single for loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a clean solution, seeing what you would like to achieve. It would be better to get all the pixels in one shot, and then process them in the parallel for.

An alternative that I personally used, and improved the performance dramatically, is doing this conversion using unsafe functions to output a grayscale image.

```
public static byte[] MakeGrayScaleRev(byte[] source, ref Bitmap bmp,int Hei,int Wid)
        {            
            int bytesPerPixel = 4;   

            byte[] bytesBig = new byte[Wid * Hei]; //create array to contain bitmap data with padding

            unsafe
            {

                int ic = 0, oc = 0, x = 0;
                //Convert the pixel to it's luminance using the formula:
                // L = .299*R + .587*G + .114*B
                //Note that ic is the input column and oc is the output column                  
                for (int ind = 0, i = 0; ind < 4 * Hei * Wid; ind += 4, i++)
                {                        
                    int g = (int)
                            ((source[ind] / 255.0f) *
                            (0.301f * source[ind + 1] +
                             0.587f * source[ind + 2] +
                            0.114f * source[ind + 3]));
                    bytesBig[i] = (byte)g;
                }    
            }

            try
            {

                bmp = new Bitmap(Wid, Hei, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

                bmp.Palette = GetGrayScalePalette();

                Rectangle dimension = new Rectangle(0, 0, Wid, Hei);
                BitmapData picData = bmp.LockBits(dimension, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);


                IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

                Marshal.Copy(forpictures, 0, pixelStartAddress, forpictures.Length);

                bmp.UnlockBits(picData);

                return bytesBig;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);

                return null;

            }

        }
```

It gets the bytearray of all the pixels of the input image, its height and width and output the computed grayscale array, and in ref Bitmap bmp the output grayscale bitmap.

Comment: +1 Thanks. This could be helpful for someone but I might not use this one as of now for some other reason

Comment: let me know if you need any help. This code was used to get stream from an RTSP camera and convert it to grayscale, so performance was crucial.